# Solr/Lucene Multivalued Fields - maximum number of values?

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there an actual or practical limit to the number of values that can be placed in a multivalued field in Solr/Lucene?

For example, if I want to have an indexed field with 5000 numeric values, will this cause problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, not many: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.solr.user/22626

Comment: You need to provide us with more information: will these numbers be unique or nearly unique, if no what is the expected number of unique values? What kind of queries will you perform with these numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You question requires bit more context. It depends on how the field will be used.. Apparently going by the amount of data in the field, features like faceting wont make much sense..

Performance wise, it might be worth noting,

- Document Cache will take up relatively more memory.
- if it is part of copyField you have to careful about potential index size increase.

There is no definitive answer, the best is to create test data set & benchmark it with what you intend to do & see the behavior.